# Using htaccess to restrict access to a directory

Tags: php, html, mysql, .htaccess

I'm currently developing a website using PHP and mySQL to handle the database operations. However, the ajax files used to retrieve the data from the database are easily accessible on the server, if a user knows how to find them.

I'd like to know whether I can use htaccess to restrict access to a folder, where I would be placing the php files, and how to do it, and retrieve them using a data-url in the html file.

Answer (score 2):

Create site/foldername/.htaccess file and add this line:

```
Deny from all
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, the php files that handle the db access based on a request (AJAX or whatever) MUST be able to be called, right?

That means that there is little to no point "protecting" them. Every browser on the internet can call them, so you need another approach. (Also: everybody can see the URL your HXR uses with little effort by reading the source javascript in your page)

If you don't want access to the functionality, make sure a user must log in first, and use the $_SESSION to check if the user can use the functionality.

PS: I expect your php files are readable, but not writable, by apache. You should be the only one that can write them.